# How to retrieve a website via HTTP?

Tags: java, android

i have this application force close with this code, what i do wrong?

```
public void buscaAno(View v){

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sapires.netne.net/teste.php?formato=json&idade=55");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        final String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idade);
        tv.setText(str);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you executing this code in the main thread? Are you getting a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is onClick listener and it does a blocking operation on main thread which in turn causes ANR or NetworkOnMainThreadException. You should probably use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for your purpose.

For example, you could extend AsyncTask the following way:

```
    private class PostRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strings[0]);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Handle exception here
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idade);
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
    public void buscaAno(View v) {
        new PostRequestTask().execute("http://sapires.netne.net/teste.php?formato=json&idade=55");
    }
```